# res.send not giving any response

Tags: javascript, html

This is my `index.js` I wanted the route to send  the last time stamp that I requested the `last.txt` route.
I wrote this code establish an express sever but when I request GET from insomnia I received nothing?

can anyone help me out

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});


router.get('/last.txt', function(req, res, next){
  date = new Date().toString();
  res.send(res.send(date) );

});

module.exports = router;
```

[image]

Comment: Because you are returing `""` in `res.send()`

Comment: it still didnt work

Comment: how are you initialising the express app? It's possible that these routes aren't getting mounted properly

Answer (score -1):

You're passing `date` into `res.send` before defining it. You also don't need to pass it to the `String` constructor, you can just do `res.send(date)` if you put the line `date = new Date().toString();` immediately before the `res.send(date)` line.

Comment: i did as you said but i still have no response or reply

Comment: @Alzain can you update your post to include your new code?

Comment: i updated it, sorry  about the late reply my place had a black out

Comment: @Alzain Hi, in the last.txt route you have written res.send(res.send(date)). But it should be res.send(date).

Comment: Seconding what @KonohaNinja said, the line should just be `res.send(date)`.

Comment: OP is not wanting to send the current timestamp, they want to save the timestamp of the last request and send it in the next request (ie. each request should return the timestamp of the request before it). Quote: "send the last time stamp that I requested the last.txt route". The new edit changes it to returning the current timestamp, so doesn't meet the requirement